# How to connect single orbeon with dynamic databases when user changes

Tags: postgresql, liferay, orbeon

As of now I have orbeon connecting to the my postgres database (database name:orbeondb).but i want orbeon to connect with multiple databases based on some condition.

For example if user1 comes to use orbeon it connects with orbeondb and if user2 comes to use orbeon it connects to orbeondb1.I want to change the connection dynamically based on some conditions.

Actually I am using liferay with orbeon and I want different users to use their own different orbeon forms. Can anyone have any idea about this.
can we create multiple connection for orbeon to connect with different databases.

Answer (score 0):

In Orbeon Forms 3.9 it was possible for you to tell Orbeon Forms which datasource to use by setting the `Orbeon-Datasource` header, e.g. in a web app filter or reverse proxy. For more on this, see the section *Dynamic datasource for MySQL* in the [3.9 database documentation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers).

However that feature was almost never used, and hasn't been maintained in the 4.x releases, in part because 4.x supports having multiple datasources for the same database, and selecting which one to use based on the app/form name. This allows you to "partition" forms in different "apps" (e.g. for different client of yours, or different services of your organization), and have the data for the forms in each app stored in the different database.

If you really need a more general mechanism, like the `Orbeon-Datasource`, you might want to try it, in the off chance that it still works. If not, and this is something you need, if using the open source CE edition you can put that back in the product yourself, or if your organization has a [PE subscription](http://www.orbeon.com/pricing) you can work with Orbeon to see how to implement such a feature in a current release.